# How does the git-flow plugin integrate into IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-flow

For example,

```
git flow feature start MYFEATURE
```

Is there a way `git-flow` operations like this can be done from within IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a plugin for `git-flow` integration via IntelliJ IDEA:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7315

Getting git-flow to work via windows can be a little problematic, but once this is done then the plugin works fine, in my experience so far.

One note: (in my experience) there should not be any versioned local changes in IDEA when you first `init` gitflow in a project, otherwise it will fail. Edit: I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, as per OpherV's comment I will report it. In the meantime my solution was to "stash" any local changes before initializing the repo.

Comment: I could not find anything on getting git-flow running under Windows 10. I also would need the IDEA plugin to work, but the how-to's seem outdated. Any clues on how to properly set up git-flow for windows 10?

Comment: Windows installation is unique. Try this: https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/wiki/Installing-on-Windows

Comment: Yes, that was my starting point. However, when installing GitHub I do not get a folder like "C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_8810fd5c2c79c73adcc73fd0825f3b32fdb816e7\bin", so I am stuck at this point of the installation. I don't know if this is because of a newer GitHub for Windows release or because of Windows 10.

Comment: I'm the dev for the plugin you mentioned. What do you mean by "should not be any versioned local changed in IDEA when you first init gitflow in a project, otherwise it will fail"? If you encountered a bug please report it in the github issue tracker and I'll gladly have a look at it :)

Comment: @OpherV in my experience if I had modified any files referenced by git then the init would fail. Let's say I modified a source file - should the init be able to work? And by the way thank you for the plugin, it is really awesome :)

Comment: @vikingsteve yes it should, as long as you don't have any uncommitted changes! If your experience was different and you can reproduce please report it. In any case lets take this discussion offline :)

Comment: Looks like the plugin mentioned above no longer works in the 2020 IntelliJ versions :(